# Proving that if $a \mid (b + c)$ and $a \mid b$, then $a \mid c$. Am I on the right track?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

> For all $a, b, c \in \mathbb{Z}$, if $a \mid (b + c)$ and $a \mid b$, then $a \mid c$.

Proof: Let $a,b,c$ be integers. Suppose $a\mid(b+c)$ and $a\mid b$. Then $(b+c) = ap$ and $b = aq$ where $p$ and $q$ are integers. By substitution $[b+c = ap]$ is equivalent to $[aq+c = ap]$ which simplifies to $c=ap-aq$. Therefore, $c=a(p-q)$ and thus $a \mid c$.

> Am I on the right track with this proof? TIA

Comment: I think it's all right!

Comment: The logic and language is pretty good. Some nit picky critiques: Introduce variables before you use them. The third sentence would be improved by writing: Then *there exist integers $p,q$ such that $(b+c) = ap$ and $b = aq$.* Optionally, for the pedants in the way back, you could include your rationale: Then, *by the definition of divisibility, there exist integers $p,q$ such that $(b+c) = ap$ and $b = aq$.* Finally, try and find some similes for therefore so as to not repeat yourself too much.

Comment: One other very minor point.  People often use $p$ and $q$ to represent primes.  When an arbitrary integer is meant, people often use $m, n, k$.  This is purely a matter of style -- you were clear that you were using $p$ and $q$ to represent integers, not necessarily primes.